# firebase objective c query

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to retrieve the objects for which the current user uid is set to yes with the following function, which does not seem to work.

```
- (void)configureDatabase {
    _ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

    FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

    _refHandle = [[[[_ref child:@"tasks"] queryOrderedByChild:@"appliedByUsers"] queryEqualToValue:@YES childKey:user.uid] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)

    {

    NSLog(@"snapshot: %@", snapshot);

    [_tasks addObject:snapshot];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_tasks.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}]; }
```

> ```
> tasks
>    -Kj3BawmhKjqbZXZdicq
>      applicationStatus: 
>      appliedByUsers
>        bNDJtrn1Mmh51GXHTbMNR1MiTZt1: true
>        hUI0W0TZxObazIFxSRm8t990UgM2: true
>      price: 
>      source: 
>      taskName: 
>      type: 
> .
> .
> .
> ```

how do I retrieve the tasks for which the current user.uid is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing `user.uid` with `childKey` specify it with `queryOrderedByChild` with `appliedByUsers`.

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

_refHandle = [[[[_ref child:@"tasks"] queryOrderedByChild:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"appliedByUsers/%@",user.uid]] 
                  queryEqualToValue:@YES]                                       
                  observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded 
                  withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

     NSLog(@"snapshot: %@", snapshot);

     [_tasks addObject:snapshot];
     [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_tasks.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}];
```

**Note:** If your value `true` is not boolean and string that it is `queryEqualToValue:@"true"]`

Comment: Thank you Nirav!
I cannot add @"appliedByUsers/user.uid" because it gives me the following error: 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(queryOrderedByChild:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'' 

is there another way to append user.uid to the path?

Comment: Great! Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore also lets you specify the sort order for your data and specify a limit to how many documents you want to retrieve using orderBy() and limit(). For example, you could query for the first 3 cities alphabetically with:

```
[[citiesRef queryOrderedByField:@"name"] queryLimitedTo:3];
```

You could also sort in descending order to get the last 3 cities:

```
[[citiesRef queryOrderedByField:@"name" descending:YES] queryLimitedTo:3];
```

You can also order by multiple fields. For example, if you wanted to order by state, and within each state order by population in descending order:

```
[[citiesRef queryOrderedByField:@"state"] queryOrderedByField:@"population" 
            descending:YES];
```

You can combine where() filters with orderBy() and limit(). In the following example, the queries define a population threshold, sort by population in ascending order, and return only the first few results that exceed the threshold:

```
[[[citiesRef queryWhereField:@"population" isGreaterThan:@100000]
             queryOrderedByField:@"population"]
             queryLimitedTo:2];
```

However, if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field:

Valid: Range filter and orderBy on the same field

```
[[citiesRef queryWhereField:@"population" isGreaterThan:@100000]
            queryOrderedByField:@"population"];
```

Invalid: Range filter and first orderBy on different fields

```
[[citiesRef queryWhereField:@"population" isGreaterThan:@100000]  
            queryOrderedByField:@"country"];
```